# Runkit - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: json, node.js, runkit

```
var cors = require("cors");

cors({ origin: '*' });
cors({ allowHeaders: 'X-PINGOTHER'});
cors({ methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE'});

exports.endpoint = function(request, response) {
    let text = '100,000';
    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    response.end(text);
}
```

I am running this on Runkit and still get the error when checking on a website, where I want to display this return value:
"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be a complete [mcve], and your use of `cors()` doesn't seem to match the examples in [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) at all.

Comment: try to allow `OPTION` methods

Answer (score 2):

In your example you've loaded the `cors` module and configured it, but not actually done anything to get it to intercept the HTTP request and send back your CORS headers.

If you're just using a simple Runkit endpoint, you don't need the CORS module at all – just add the headers in your endpoint, where you're already adding the `Content-Type` header:

```
exports.endpoint = function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
    });
    res.end('foo');
};
```